# Moving textView/textField to top while keyboard appearance

Tags: ios, text, textview, uitextfield

How can i move `textView`/`textField` to top of view when I select one of them?

Comment: Google is a developer's best friend.

Answer (score 2):

Working code....

**1) set `delegate` to you `textFields`**

```
[self.textField setDelegate:self];
```

**2) To move `textField` up**

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.textField)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x , (self.view.frame.origin.y - 80), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

**3) To move `textField` down**

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.textField)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x , (self.view.frame.origin.y + 80), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

**4) to move `textView` Up**

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView == self.textView)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x , (self.view.frame.origin.y - 80), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

**5) to move `textView` Down**

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView == self.textView)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x , (self.view.frame.origin.y + 80), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```